# Incremental Load with ADF pipeline Copy activity

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-data-factory

I am implementing a ingestion framework in ADF where my source is mySQL server. For incremental the column that i am referring to is "lastUpdate:timestamp". so for this after the initial load i am taking the max(lastUpdate) and writing as a string in a file and for incremental my pipeline is starting with a look up activity where i am reading that value and then comparing in the copy activity. Below is code sample of the SQL query that i am using in the query of the ADF pipeline of copy activity

```
select * from dbo.mfgoperationdata where lastUpdate > to_timestamp('@{activity('MaxDate').output.firstRow.Prop_0}','yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ');
```

The max value that is stored is of format "2022-09-22T21:02:38.000+0000"

But with this i am getting an error pasted below

[image]

can someone help me to rectify the format that i am using as expression.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that the format of the timestamp value in your SQL query is not recognized by the MySQL server(source). MySQL server doesn't have `to_timestamp()` function.
[image]

You can use the  `formatDateTime()`  ADF function to convert the timestamp value to this format instead of `to_timestamp()` function. The Query is modified as below:

```
select * from dbo.mfgoperationdata where lastUpdate > '@{formatDateTime(activity('MaxDate').output.firstRow.Prop_0, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')}';
```

[image]

In this modified SQL query, the  `formatDateTime()`  function is used to convert the timestamp value to the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff'.  This solves the error and pipeline is executed without any error.